# Cosine inequality with an inside function

Tags: inequality, trigonometry

If we have $$\cos(2x - 120) < \cos(30)$$ for $0 < x < 180$, I know one of the intervals is $75 < x < 180$.

I did this by looking at the unit circle and drawing a hypotenuse of angle $30^○$ and $330^○$, and marking the $x$ axis where the $x$ value is less than $\cos(30^○)$

But apparently $0 < x < 45$ is also an interval. What is the intuition of this?

Comment: In what interval are you seeking solutions?

Comment: Setting $X=2x-120$ should help.

Comment: Ah, I see I found out why.  Since cos(2x - 120) = cos(120 - 2x), we can use the RHS instead of the LHS. So cos(120 - 2x) < cos(30) using my method in the question, we have 30 < 120 - 2x < 330, simplifying we have -105 < x < 45, but the interval in question is in 0 < x < 180, s0 0 < x < 45 is also an interval.

Comment: The numbers are in degrees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did not take into account is that two coterminal angles have the same cosine.

We wish to solve the inequality
$$\cos(2x - 120^\circ) < \cos(30^\circ)$$
in the interval $(0^\circ, 180^\circ)$.

Since $\cos(30^\circ) = \sqrt{3}/2$ the inequality is true if
$$30^\circ < 2x - 120^\circ < 330^\circ$$
as you observed.  However, it is also true for any angles coterminal with these angles.  Therefore, we wish to find $x$ satifying $0^\circ < x < 180^\circ$ such that
$$30^\circ + 360^\circ n < 2x - 120^\circ < 330^\circ + 360^\circ n$$
where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.
\begin{align*}
30^\circ + 360^\circ n & < 2x - 120^\circ < 330^\circ + 360^\circ n\\
150^\circ + 360^\circ n & < 2x < 450^\circ + 360^\circ n\\
75^\circ + 180^\circ n & < x < 225^\circ + 180^\circ n
\end{align*}
When $n = 0$, we obtain $75^\circ < x < 225^\circ$.  Restricting to the interval $(0^\circ, 180^\circ)$ yields $75^\circ < x < 180^\circ$, which was your initial solution.

However, we also obtain angles in the interval $(0^\circ, 180^\circ)$ when $n = -1$.  If $n = -1$, we obtain $-105^\circ < x < 45^\circ$. Restricting to the interval $(0^\circ, 180^\circ)$ yields $0^\circ < x < 45^\circ$.

Thus, the solution set in the interval $0^\circ < x < 180^\circ$ is $S = (0^\circ, 45^\circ) \cup (75^\circ, 180^\circ)$.

**Alternate Method:** The inequality
$$\cos(2x - 120^\circ) < \cos(30^\circ)$$
is *not* true if
$$-30^\circ + 360^\circ k \leq 2x - 120^\circ \leq 30^\circ + 360^k$$
where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.
\begin{align*}
-30^\circ + 360^\circ k &\leq 2x - 120^\circ \leq 30^\circ + 360^\circ k\\
90^\circ + 360^\circ k & \leq 2x \leq 150^\circ + 360^\circ k\\
45^\circ + 180^\circ k & \leq x \leq 75^\circ + 180^\circ k
\end{align*}
To find angles in the interval $(0^\circ, 180^\circ)$ where the inequality $\cos(2x - 120^\circ) < \cos(30^\circ)$ is not true, we set $k = 0$, which yields $45^\circ \leq x \leq 75^\circ$.  Therefore, the original inequality is true in the interval $(0^\circ, 180^\circ)$ if $0^\circ < x < 45^\circ$ or $75^\circ < x < 180^\circ$.

Comment: I see, I didn't realize that in my method, there was the second coterminal angle, which is 330 (Q4) and 390 degrees (Q1). Then the second interval is simply 330 < 2x - 120 < 390, taking account the intervals we want we have 0 < x < 45 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

As $\cos(360^\circ n-A)=+\cos A$ and

for $\cos C>\cos D$ if $0<C<D<90^\circ$

the proposition will be true iff

$$ 360^\circ n +360^\circ -30^\circ >2x-120^\circ>360^\circ n +30^\circ$$ where $n$ is any integer

$$\iff180^\circ n+(165+60)^\circ> x>180^\circ n+(60+15)^\circ $$